# Excel Percentage formatting and average

Tags: excel, excel-formula, percentage

I have these percentages in excel:

[image: Percentages]

I have to format them as .000 so for example, 17% has to be .170 and 100% has to be 1.000. Additionally, I need to calculate the Average of these percentages but I always get an error. also using AVERAGEIF nothing is changing.
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is the *exact* content of these cells? How are they formatted?

Comment: According to your regional settings is , or . your decimal separator?

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue.

Comment: Try `ISNUMBER()` on one of your cells. Does this return `TRUE` or `FALSE`? If it returns `FALSE`, then you are trying to do math with *text values* masquerading as *numerical values*

Comment: As @RicardoDiaz said it was also an issue of the decimal separator. mine is ,
Now, I have it shown as 23,1% but I would like the to be shown as  number in this format: .231

Comment: @urdearboy TRUE

Comment: @cybernetic.nomad the content is .000 and I formatted it as percentages with 3 Decimal Places

Comment: Try selecting the cells and applying the following custom format: `.000_ ;-.000` to them